# Diferenças entre incluir um detalhe/observação entre vírgulas, parênteses ou travessões

Tags: diferenças, pontuação

Quando se quer acrescentar um detalhe, observação ou breve explicação de passagem sobre algo citado, qual é a diferença entre separar com vírgulas, parênteses ou travessões?

Há, claro, casos em que usar vírgula pode talvez gerar confusões, como:

> E logo me apresentou à mulher — uma estimável senhora — e à filha.
>   [(Machado de Assis, *Memória Póstumas de Brás Cubas*.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=7jZyDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT100&dq=%22E%20logo%20me%20apresentou%20%C3%A0%20mulher%20uma%20estim%C3%A1vel%20senhora%20e%20%C3%A0%20filha%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVq8mksonPAhVIwBQKHVJdC44Q6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=%22E%20logo%20me%20apresentou%20%C3%A0%20mulher%20uma%20estim%C3%A1vel%20senhora%20e%20%C3%A0%20filha%22&f=false)

Se fosse usada vírgula no lugar do travessão, poderia talvez ser um pouco ambíguo e fazer com que "uma estimável senhora" talvez parecesse ser uma terceira pessoa, dependendo da interpretação.

Porém há outros casos em que não é tão óbvio saber qual sinal é o mais apropriado, como por exemplo:

> João, aquele do carro azul, também apareceu na festa.
>   João (aquele do carro azul) também apareceu na festa.
>   João — aquele do carro azul — também apareceu na festa.

Ou

> Dornelles disse que Gouvêa Vieira — senador de 1963 a 1967 — foi uma grande liderança.
>   Dornelles disse que Gouvêa Vieira, senador de 1963 a 1967, foi uma grande liderança.
>   Dornelles disse que Gouvêa Vieira (senador de 1963 a 1967) foi uma grande liderança.

Eu particularmente nunca uso o travessão para outra coisa além de indicar falas, usando no lugar sempre somente parênteses ou vírgulas. Mas há situações em que é mais apropriado o travessão?

Comment: O uso do travessão em narrativas podem surgir para expressar a opinião pessoal do autor ou do narrador da estória.

Comment: Bruno, há uma coisa curiosa: «mulher, — uma estimável senhora, — e», com dois travessões e duas vírgulas, foi como o Machado de Assis escreveu. Hoje em dia, seria só travessões, sem nenhuma vírgula. Só com uma vírgula, «mulher, — uma estimável senhora — e», que é como tu tinhas e se encontra em muitos sites, não me parece fazer sentido nenhum, e não corresponde a nenhuma edição do livro no Google Books. Achei melhor deixar sem vírgula, como se escreve hoje.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualquer destes sinais, em pares, servem para isolar palavras ou frases. As fronteiras entre os usos de uns e de outros não são rígidas, mas basicamente os travessões realçam, os parênteses esbatem, e as vírgulas são neutras. Por isso os parênteses são geralmente usados para intercalar apartes acessórios — coisas que poderiam ser omitidas, que frequentemente o leitor pode saltar —, enquanto as vírgulas e travessões isolam partes que são para ser lidas em articulação com o texto circundante, mas que precisam de ser isoladas por uma questão de legibilidade ou ênfase. Os travessões são mais enfáticos, dão mais destaque ao texto, do que as vírgulas.

O exemplo seguinte, retirado da *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Sintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 834), principal obra em que se baseia esta resposta (p. 806-14 e 830-35), ilustra o uso dos três sinais:

> (c) Abel, sem responder, sem voltar-se para mim, cinge mais forte — e não sem brandura — os meus dedos. (Osman Lins, [*Alvorada*, 1975, p.] 64-65.)

A frase básica é simplesmente, «Abel […] cinge mais forte […] os meus dedos», mas Osman Lins decidiu adicionar mais três informações: «sem responder», «sem voltar-se para mim» e «não sem brandura». As duas primeiras vão entre vírgulas; a terceira, entre travessões. Creio que é claro que a terceira — entre travessões — ganha mais destaque que as outras. Isto foi uma opção do autor, que quis destacar «não sem brandura». Por fim, a referência bibliográfica — informação acessória que o leitor poderá querer saltar — vem, como é habitual, dentro de parênteses. (Incluí entre colchetes material que não faz parte da passagem original da *Nova Gramática*; no original está apenas, «Osman Lins, *A*, 64-65». E temos aqui mesmo outro exemplo de um aparte acessório que podes ou não querer saltar.)

Portanto o autor é que tem de decidir se prefere travessões ou vírgulas, conforme queira enfatizar mais ou menos o texto a isolar. Os parênteses, pelo contrário, tendem a reduzir a importância do texto. Usamo-los frequentemente para dar explicações adicionais que não são importantes, mas poderão ainda assim interessar a alguns leitores. Exemplos aleatórios da *Nova Gramática*:

> Nas obras impressas os elementos sublinhados vêm em tipo diverso, preferentemente em itálico (ou grifo). (p. 829)
>
> [Emprega-se ainda a vírgula] para indicar a supressão de uma palavra (geralmente um verbo) ou de um grupo de palavras (p. 809)

Na escolha entre vírgulas e travessões, por vezes, para além da ênfase, põe-se a questão da legibilidade. Se o texto a isolar for longo, e especialmente se ele mesmo contiver vírgulas, poderá ser preferível usar travessões, como neste exemplo do [Manual de Comunicação da Secom (Senado Federal do Brasil)](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/travessao):

> Isso porque, neste mês, encerra-se o prazo — dado pelo Decreto 6.514/2008, sucessivamente prorrogado por novos decretos — para averbação das áreas de reserva legal.

Outro uso comum dos travessões é para intercalar observações do narrador no discurso direto da personagem. Neste caso o discurso direto abre também com travessão. Exemplo da *Nova Gramática* (p. 834):

> — A Igreja — atalhou o Bispo — não pode desinteressar-se do problema social. (Sophia de Mello Breyner Andersen, [*Contos Exemplares*, 6.ª edição, p.] 36.)

Os parênteses são ainda normalmente usados para, entre outros apartes acessórios a que não se quer dar especial destaque, informação biográfica:

> Pedro Álvares Cabral (Belmonte, 1467 ou 1468 – Santarém, c. 1520) foi um fidalgo, comandante militar, navegador e explorador […]  [(Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_%C3%81lvares_Cabral)

E também para a «citação textual de uma palavra ou frase traduzida» (*Nova Gramática*, p. 831):

> (a) Parece que o duunvirato jurisdicional (*duunviri* ou *quatuorviri juridicundo*), já muito cerceada a sua jurisdição nos últimos tempos do império, deixou de existir. (Serafim da Silva Neto, [*História da Língua Portuguesa*, 1970, p.] 319.)

Na literatura criativa encontram-se outros usos interessantes dos parênteses, que, ao contrário do habitual, realçam o texto. Estes dois exemplos são da *Nova Gramática* (p. 830-31):

> Conseguia controlar a bola que me passavam (quando passavam) jogando em geral (quando deixavam) na ponta direita, por ser pequenino mas veloz. (Fernando Sabino, [*O menino no espelho*, 1982, p.] 145.)
>
> Havia a escola, que era azul e tinha
> Um mestre mau, de assustador pigarro…
> (Meu Deus! que é isto? que emoção a minha
> Quando estas coisas tão singelas narro?)
> [Bernardino da Costa Lopes, *Helenos*, 1901, p. 65.]

Parece-me que aqui os autores optaram por parênteses para mais claramente indicarem que as observações são apartes. Mas o seu conteúdo é interessante e tem carga emocional, de modo que o aparte acaba sendo realçado; mais do que se tivessem sido usados travessões ou vírgulas, pois estes não dariam a ideia de aparte.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que as diferenças sejam basicamente de estilo.

Alguns veículos jornalísticos ou editoras, por exemplo, podem preferir ou restringir o uso de um dos sinais.

Nos seus dois exemplos, todos os sinais funcionam bem.

Answer (score 2):

- > João, aquele do carro azul, também apareceu na festa.

Vírgula não é usada nesse caso em específico, se fosse mais de uma característica, o uso da vírgula poderia ser aceito. Exemplo:

- > João, aquele do carro azul e pneu furado, também apareceu na festa.

No caso dos parênteses:

- > João (aquele do carro azul) também apareceu na festa.

Parênteses são usados (neste contexto) para relembrar ou dar ênfase em um detalhe que possa ter sido perdido nas entrelinhas do texto. Isso significa que esta frase só seria aceitável caso o carro azul já fora citado no texto antes, e para tal, usando-se o hífen como demostrado a seguir:

- > João — e seu arrojado carro azul — também apareceu na festa.

Essas regras se aplicam em narrativas, artigos de opinião e até certo ponto, em poesias.

Comment: Nokdef, muito didática sua explicação, porém senti falta de referências. Podes citar regras para suas asserções?