# Duas datas entre parênteses no currículo

Tags: pontuação

No meu currículo escrevi as datas entre parênteses, mas uma tradutora tirou alguns desses parênteses e colocou as datas após a um travessão, assim:

• Madinah Arabic, Londres — De maio de 2013 a fevereiro de 2016

• italki, Hong Kong — De junho de 2013 a novembro de 2016

*Isso é parte da experiência como professora.

Acho que ela faz isso porque entre esses parênteses tinha duas datas, por exemplo (maio de 2013-fevereiro de 2016), mas entre os outros parentêses, que ela deixou, apenas tinha uma data.

Comment: Para mim, é muito mais comum o travessão. Não lembro de ver entre parênteses. Mas não sei uma regra geral para isso. No final, acho que os dois podem ser considerados corretos.

Comment: Muito obrigada. Aprecio sua ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesse caso, terias três opções: parentêses, travessões ou vírgulas. Como nesse caso, acredito que o objetivo é destacar o tempo ou período que esteve trabalhando em cada companhia, utilizaria o travessão.

Para mais informações, há uma questão que tem detalhadamente o uso de cada uma dessas pontuações.

[Diferenças entre incluir um detalhe/observação entre vírgulas, parênteses ou travessões](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-incluir-um-detalhe-observa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-v%C3%ADrgulas-par%C3%AAnteses-ou-tra)

Comment: Obrigada. Aprecio muito sua ajuda.